# Async not awaiting function before running

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, cheerio, request-promise

I'm trying to parse a specification website from saved HTML on my computer. I can post the file upon request.

I'm burnt out trying to figure out why it won't run synchronously. The comments should log the `CCCC`'s first, then `BBBB`'s, then finally one `AAAA`.

The code I'm running will not wait at the first hurdle (it prints `AAAA...` first). Am I using `request-promise` incorrectly? What is going on?

Is this due to the `.each()` method of `cheerio` (I'm assuming it's synchronous)?

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const fs = require('fs');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

async function parseAutodeskSpec(contentsHtmlFile) {
  const topics = [];
  const contentsPage = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync(contentsHtmlFile).toString());
  const contentsSelector = '.content_htmlbody table td div div#divtreed0e338374 nobr .toc_entry a.treeitem';

  contentsPage(contentsSelector).each(async (idx, topicsAnchor) => {
    const topicsHtml = await rp(topicsAnchor.attribs['href']);
    console.log("topicsHtml.length: ", topicsHtml.length);
  });

  console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");

  return topics;
}
```

Comment: I would guess it is because of `.each`, but I'm not completely sure tbh. Have you tried converting the result of `contentsPage(contentsSelector)` into an Array (if it isn't already) and then use the `for .. of ..` syntax?

Comment: The problem could be this `const topicsPage = cheerio.load(topicsHtml);`. I think it should be something like `const topicsPage = await cheerio.load(topicsHtml);`

Comment: @KubwimanaAdrien Makes no difference if there's an `await` keyword or not

Comment: Looking at the source code for [`.each`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/master/lib/api/traversing.js#L298) it looks like it's a synchronous function.  There shouldn't be a need for the `await` keyword before calling `.each`

Comment: @TheF1rstPancake Without `await` it outputs `AAAAA ... \n topicsHtml.length:  10128`. So I have no idea

Comment: I think it has to do with the async call occurring in `.each`... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @lumio, you seem to have the right idea!

Comment: Same with you @bsapaka, thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
let hrefs = contentsPage(contentsSelector).map((idx, topicsAnchor) => {
  return topicsAnchor.attribs['href']
}).get()


let topicsHtml
for(href of hrefs){
  topicsHtml = await rp(href);
  console.log("topicsHtml.length: ", topicsHtml.length);
}
```

Now the await is outside of map or each which doesn't quite work the way you think.

Comment: This is a great answer! I think `.toArray` is slightly more appropriate here? But Reading upon it, I'm unsure if it really makes a difference though, past readability. You were definitely on the right path about not using a `Promise` of any sort within the `map()` - it doesn't seem to honour the synchronicity that way. Is that a general callback thing, or just a quirk of `cheerio`?

Comment: It's not just cheerio, js map works the same way. The way I look at is the await will prevent the code below it from running before it comes back but not the iterator (higher order function?) itself from continuing.

Comment: Thanks, accepted as the answer as this achieved what I needed. I've "improved" it a little for my needs in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As @lumio stated in his comment, I also think that this is because of the `each` function being synchrone.

You should rather use the `map` method, and use the `Promise.all()` on the result to wait enough time:

```
const obj = contentsPage(contentsSelector).map(async (idx, topicsAnchor) => {
  const topicsHtml = await rp(topicsAnchor.attribs['href']);
  console.log("topicsHtml.length: ", topicsHtml.length);

  const topicsFromPage = await parseAutodeskTopics(topicsHtml)
  console.log("topicsFromPage.length: ", topicsFromPage.length);

  topics.concat(topicsFromPage);
})

const filtered = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => !isNaN(key)).map(key => obj[key])

await Promise.all(filtered)

console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
```

Comment: Nope, throws an error. `Promise.all` takes an array of functions! `map` is synchronous too so I'm not sure I follow why that's important here

Comment: @NickBull [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) takes an iterable of _promises_, not an iterable of functions. Since an `async` function always returns a `Promise`, this should in theory work. Maybe you could help by actually elaborating what the error is and which line it occurs on in the snippet you've provided.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Sorry, you are right! I should have been more specific. I meant that this returns an `Object`, not a `Promise`

Comment: Hi @NickBull I edited my answer. Note the `const filtered = ...` that transforms the object generated by the map function into an array of promises.

Comment: @Hammerbot Sorry I just remembered about this question. Unfortunately I still believe that this has issues, as `.map()` does not handle asynchronicity well in the callback. See my answer for how I've gone about avoiding that

Comment: @Hammerbot Thank you for the `Promise.all()` example though, that really helped to push the answer in the correct direction!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other answers here I came to a rather elegant conclusion. Note the avoidance of `async`/`await` in the `.map()` callback, as `cheerio`'s callbacks (and from what I've learned about `async`/`await`, generally all callbacks) seem not to honour the synchronous nature of `await` well:

```
async function parseAutodeskSpec(contentsHtmlFile) {
  const contentsPage = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync(contentsHtmlFile).toString());
  const contentsSelector = '.content_htmlbody table td div div#divtreed0e338374 nobr .toc_entry a.treeitem';

  const contentsReqs = contentsPage(contentsSelector)
    .map((idx, elem) => rp(contentsPage(elem).attr('href')))
    .toArray();

  const topicsReqs = await Promise.all(contentsReqs)
    .map(req => parseAutodeskTopics(req));

  return await Promise.all(topicsReqs);
}
```